# Docker-compose volumes don't update code in container for the 2nd time

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vuejs3, devops

I have problem, my docker-compose does not pull code changes into the container on Windows 10. The same config on Ubuntu works correctly and the changes are pulled into the container. I checked the versions of docker and compose, tried to specify the full path to the Frontend folder in docker-compose, but nothing helps. The most interesting thing is that if I built docker-compose and in the frontend container with an error in the code, an error is displayed on the site, I fix it locally, reload the page and it works, that is, the code change was pulled into the container, now I change it again code for what was and 0 changes on the site.

I also tried going into the container and changing the code in it, which also does not affect what is displayed on the site. I do not understand what is going on?

Help me my docker-comrads
docker-composer.yml

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:13.3
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        environment:
            POSTGRES_USER: username
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgresql_password
            POSTGRES_DB: database_name
            PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/dbfiles
        volumes:
            - ./DbData:/var/lib/postgresql/data
           # - postgresql.conf:/etc/postgresql.conf
            - ./DbData:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
        container_name: pgdb
    nginx:
        depends_on:
            - api
            - frontend
        restart: always
        build:
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
            context: './nginx'
        ports:
            - "3050:80"
    api:
        build:
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
            context: './Backend'
        volumes:
            - ./Backend:/app
        command: "gunicorn -c gunicorn.py Backend.wsgi"
        depends_on:
            -   postgres
    frontend:
        stdin_open: true
        build:
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
            context: './Frontend'
        volumes:
            - /app/node_modules
            - ./Frontend:/app
```

Comment: Your question starts with "I have the same problem" as if you're replying to someone, but IMO you don't adequately identify _what_ the problem is.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `volumes:` for the `api` and `frontend` containers, which overwrite the code that's already built into the image.  If you delete those `volumes:` blocks, will you get predictable behavior?  (You will need to re-`docker-compose build` after making and validating local changes, not unlike re-running a build tool like Webpack.)

Comment: Yes, this is a working option, but how do you imagine a development in which after each change you need to rebuild the container? We're not in 2007

Comment: @gGodlik, are you editing the files that are mounted in the `volumes`. Also, are you using Docker desktop or Ubuntu in WSL coz the volumes attached have paths for Linux.